# Need someone to thoroughly explain this code for me (Fourier transform, sampling...)

Tags: matlab, plot

dear stackoverflow members, i have a matlab homework. and im having trouble understanding how this piece of code:

```
m = [ones(1,t0/(3*ts)),-2*ones(1,t0/(3*ts)),zeros(1,t0/(3*ts)+1)];
```

was put and what does it do? .

It is supposed to plot this function: http://s22.postimg.org/8e3ieonoh/Untitled.gif

Here's the full code:

```
t0 = 0.15;
ts = 0.001;
fc = 250;
fs = 1/ts;
df = 0.3;
t = [0:ts:t0];
m = [ones(1,t0/(3*ts)),-2*ones(1,t0/(3*ts)),zeros(1,t0/(3*ts)+1)];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates the time sequence as a long array.  `ones(1,t0/(3*ts))` means when t<=t0/3, the function obtain 1; `-2*ones(1,t0/(3*ts))` indicates the second value in the original function within the range of `[t0/3,t0/3*2]`. `zeros(1,t0/(3*ts)+1)` is the rest part of function. The time interval between two consecutive points in your curve is `ts`.

To avoid the warning, use

```
m = [ones(1,floor(t0/(3*ts))),-2*ones(1,floor(t0/(3*ts))),zeros(1,floor(t0/(3*ts))+1)];
```

Comment: but why does it say 3*ts ? whats the use of ts there? cant we use the constant 0.15 right away?

Comment: it is (t0/3)/ts, where t0/3 is from the formula in your picture. ts is the time interval, so (t0/3)/ts shows you how many points should be plotted.

Comment: why does it say Warning: Size vector should be a row vector with integer elements.  when i try to set ts = 0.025 or any value different from 0.001 ?

Comment: where do  i use it? sorry if im asking too much im so new to matlab

Comment: 1 last thing, why does it say zeros(...+1) ? what is the +1 for? im having trouble relating that with the given equation in the picture atttached.

Comment: that intends to make sure length(t) is equal to length(m), otherwise it will throw out error when you do the plot(t,m)

Comment: ok thanks alot. there is a continouty for the code, is it possible to talk to u in chat?